# Is it possible to add/alter css to a website to display a background image from your harddrive?

Tags: css

I have a chrome extension that lets me add css to any website. I am trying to put a background using an image on my harddrive, but can't get it to work.

For this example I am using www.google.com

If it makes a difference, the chrome extension I am using is called Stylebot

This the CSS I added

```
body {

background:#F9F0C9 url("file:///C:/Users/username/OneDrive/Documents/PaperPAge/5-wrinkled-parchment-paper1final2.png")  center center fixed;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;

}
```

The #F9F0C9 color is added to the background, so something is working, but selected background image does not appear.

Comment: I don't think browsers are allowed to read files from your disk without user dialogs

Comment: Is there anyway to do this in CSS? Or perhaps javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Stylebot](https://github.com/ankit/stylebot) is a Chrome extension and thus all scripts, including the CSS parser, are written in JavaScript. @C.Dhruv is correct, there is no Chrome method for arbitrarily reading files from a user's local disk without prompting them. If possible, I would recommend uploading the image to either your own public-facing webserver or some image hosting site and reference the URL accordingly in your code snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

Please change background to background-image

then your code will be

```
body {
background-color:#F9F0C9;
background-image:url("file:///C:/Users/username/OneDrive/Documents/PaperPAge/5-wrinkled-parchment-paper1final2.png") center center fixed;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

}